# R package caret, function avNNet, allow parallel does not seem to work

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I am using avNNet from R's caret package to fit a regression model. From what I understand, the function fits a number of neural networks and then averages the estimates.

There is an option called allowParallel which, if true, should use a parallel backend if loaded and available. For that purpose, I load the doMC package and set the number of cores like so:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4)
```

And then I estimate the fit like so:

```
fit <- avNNet(formula, data = training, repeats=10, size=20, decay=0.1, linout=TRUE, maxit = 3000, allowParallel=TRUE)
```

However, whether I set allowParallel to TRUE or FALSE I do not get any noticeable difference in computation time or processor load. I have a four-core processor which in both cases is loaded at around 25%.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, is there a good way to optimize the values of the options passed to avNNet, like maxit, size or decay?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: More data would be helpful. How big was the data? etc. It could be that your computational burden isn't that high so you might be getting a 4-fold speedup that decreases the execution time by .001s.

Comment: There are about 200 observations and 10 independent variables. So the data is quite manageable. Computation time varies between 16-18 seconds whether allowParallel is true or false. And CPU load is more or less 25% in both cases.

Comment: I think you don't see a difference due to the light computational burden. If you are on unix or OS X, watch `top` to see that the workers start and stop.